# ASUS RT-N66R won't allow port forwarding of 80

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

Has anyone else tried to port forward outside port 80 to inside port 80 on an ASUS RT-N66R? I just spent 3 hours trying to get a new web server functioning from the internet (which I've done quite a few times, never with this model router) and finally figured out that it was the external port being set to 80.

When I change the outside port to 8080, everything works. You may thing that this is happening because I've allowed WAN access to the console, but I have not! Is this device just "reserving" the port in case I wanted to open it up?! I also see no way of changing the management access port either. Am I stuck with having to apply a port number at the end of my url, I really hope not :(

Comment: You webserver can define what port it is running on, and if configure the correct way, you going to yourdomain.com will automatically be redirected to yourdomain:8080 but appear as yourdomain.com.  Port 80 and 443 are just the standard ports, your website, can be assigned to any port.  With regards to your question about the firmware, if it really already assigned the its remote management functionality to port 80, you can always just disable that functionality if there is an option to disable it.  As for a way of changing the port, I have no idea, thats what OpenWRT/DD-WRT is for.

Comment: I just set the forward to "8080 to 8080", changed the listening port to 8080 on the web server, changed the virtual host statement to 8080 in 000-default.conf, restarted the service and now i get a connection refused.

Comment: Also, turned the firewall off for testing.

Comment: It sure seems that I'll need to use 8080, without being able to port forward 80, the browser would always try 80, no?

Comment: You can configure your website to run on any port you want, and you don't have to type in yourdomain.com:port, to access the website.

Comment: I get that, which I did 8080.  But from outside the LAN, if someone types in  domain.com, it automatically uses port 80, correct?  So the only way (I know of) around this is to either port forward at the router from 80 to 8080 (which my router is not letting me do) or to port map at the server, which does not apply in this case because 80 can't forward through the router, if this is not correct, please help point me in the right direction...

Comment: "if someone types in domain.com, it automatically uses port 80, correct?" - it does not.  Using port 80 is a standard, but once again, its not required to be port 80.  [Configure Apache to listen on port other than 80](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80).  What port will be used to connect to your website when somebody types in yourdomain.com is covered by your dns server.  [Vhosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: This is exactly how SSL works by the way, you don't have to navigate a secure connection by going to yourdomain.com:443

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-hostnames-or-other-ways-to-resolve-to-a-specific-ipport

Comment: "What port will be used to connect to your website when somebody types in your domain.com is convered by your dns server" BINGO!  This was the disconnect I did not know!  Thank you so much!  Put the above in the answer and I'll mark it.  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't have enough information about your server configuration to do that.  I suggest you self-answer this question.  I provided the documentation I thought was relevant for that reason.